# extract legend from plot A and add it to plot B

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to extract the exact legend from `template` and add it to `p`.

```
library(ggplot2)
hc <- c("#00000000", heat.colors(4, alpha = 1))
ds <- cbind(expand.grid(1:4,1:4),z=sample(200:300,16))

p <-ggplot(ds, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
    geom_raster(aes(fill = z)) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours=hc) +
    theme( 
        legend.position="bottom",
    ) +
    ggtitle("My title")

tmp <- cbind(expand.grid(1:10,1:10),z=1:100)
template <-ggplot(tmp, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
    geom_raster(aes(fill = z)) + 
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours=hc,breaks=c(25,50,75,100) ,labels=paste0(c(25,50,75,100),"%"),limits=c(1,100))  +
    theme( 
        legend.position="bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank()
    ) +
    ggtitle("My template")
```

I have tried stuff like:

```
p$scales <- template$scales
```

and "play" around with

```
g <- ggplotGrob(template)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution uses `ggplot_build` and `ggplot_gtable` to extract legend and then simply put it into other plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
# Extract legend from ggplot object
extractLegend <- function(gg) {
    grobs <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(gg))
    foo <- which(sapply(grobs$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
    grobs$grobs[[foo]]
}

# Extract wanted legend
wantedLegend <- extractLegend(template)

# Extract grobs from plot
grobsToReplace <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
foo <- which(sapply(grobsToReplace$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
# Replace legend with wanted legend
grobsToReplace$grobs[[foo]] <- wantedLegend
plot(grobsToReplace)
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Comment: i will test it tomorrow and then check it as answer. Looks like it does exactly what i want.

Comment: @AndreElrico And what do you exactly want ?

Comment: Does the job perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether [`cowplot::get_legend`](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/) was around back when this question was first posted, but combining that with `cowplot::plot_grid` (or another plot layout function from packages like [`patchwork`](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/) or [`egg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/index.html)) lets you easily extract a legend and add it to a different `ggplot` object.

```r
library(ggplot2)
cowplot::plot_grid(
  p + theme(legend.position = "none"),
  cowplot::get_legend(template),
  ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(5, 1)
)
```

[image]

Mess around with the heights ratio in `rel_heights` as you see fit.